# Kotlin Context with higher order functions?

Tags: kotlin

How does one define higher order functions with contexts?

Here's a simple example.

```kotlin
interface MyContext {
    fun herp()
}

// How does one invoke f with the context as receiver?
context(MyContext)
fun contextualizedHigherOrderFunction(f: MyContext.() -> Unit) {
    f() // nope
    this.f() // nope
}
```

How do I get the context into the receiver of `f`?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the context receiver by using a [qualified `this` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/this-expressions.html#qualified-this). You can use the type name as the label in this case

```
this@MyContext.f()
```

Alternatively, pass it as a parameter:

```
f(this@MyContext)
```

For more complicated receiver type names, see how they translate to a label [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/context-receivers.md#referencing-specific-receiver).

Comment: Nice!  And prompt!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

@Sweeper's answer works great.  Also, you can just ignore the context in the type of `f`.  Both are presented, below:

```kotlin
interface MyContext {
    fun boom()
}

// You can specify and bind the context explicitly.
context(MyContext)
fun contextualizedHigherOrderFunction1(f: MyContext.() -> Unit) {
    this@MyContext.f()
}

// Or not!
context(MyContext)
fun contextualizedHigherOrderFunction2(f: () -> Unit) {
    f()
}

context(MyContext)
fun thingy() {
    boom()
}

fun main() {
    val myContext = object : MyContext {
        override fun boom() {
            println("boom")
        }
    }
    with(myContext) {
        boom()
        contextualizedHigherOrderFunction1 { thingy() }
        contextualizedHigherOrderFunction2 { thingy() }
        println("out go the lights")
    }
}
```

Comment: If this compiles without special contract, I think it's a bug. Unless I missed something, `contextualizedHigherOrderFunction2` could pass `f` around to something else and execute it later without the context. Which means `thingy` here would be lacking the context it requires

Comment: Compiler flag `-Xcontext-receivers` is required.

Comment: I'm not talking about this, but about a Kotlin contract for the execution of `f`, such as "in place" execution.

Comment: @Joffrey It turns out that `cHOF2` doesn't even need any context.  It seems the context is bound at the lexical call site, much like implicit params in Scala.

Comment: https://github.com/wafna/kotlin-sandbox/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/HigherOrderContext.kt

Comment: Oh, the surrounding context is actually captured in the lambda's closure, that makes sense. Thanks